# Capitals turned into p - - - - -

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

**Which two capitals are missing from this list? Explain why.**

---

**Budapest** (: : ; : : ; : :) 
**?** (: : : ; : : : :) 
**Oslo** (؛ ؛ ؛ ؛ ؛ ؛ ؛ ؛) 
**Khartoum** (: : ; : : ; : :) 
**Tbilisi** (: ; : : : : ; :) 
**Montevideo** (: : : ; : : : :) 
**Dublin** (: : ; : : ; : :)
**?** (; : : : : : : ;)(: : ; : : ; : :)(; : : : : : : ;)
**Buenos Aires** (؛ ؛ ؛ ؛ ؛ ؛ ؛ ؛) 
**Warsaw** (: : ; : : ; : :) 
**Windhoek** (: ; : : : : ; :)
**Athens** (: : : : ; : : :)
**Tegucigalpa** (: ; : : : : ; :) 
**Cardiff** (؛ ؛ ؛ ؛ ؛ ؛ ؛ ؛)  
**Bishkek** (: ; : : : : ; :) 
**San Salvador** (: : : ; : : : :) 
**Nairobi** (; : : : : : : ;)
**Astana** (: : : : ; : : :)
**New Delhi** (: : : : ; : : :) 
**Port of Spain** (: ; : : : : ; :) 
**Niamey** (: : : : ; : : :)
**Lisbon** (؛ ؛ ؛ ؛ ؛ ؛ ؛ ؛) 
**Quito** (: : : ; : : : :) 
**Brussels** (: : ; : : ; : :)
**Jakarta** (: ; : : : : ; :) 
**Bucharest** (; : : : : : : ;)
**Belfast** (: : : ; : : : :)

Comment: Congrats on topping the HNQ list!!!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The two missing capitals are ...

> ... **Muscat**, the capital of Oman and **Doha**, the capital of Qatar.

The patterns ...

> ... consist either of eight colons and semi-colons or of eight upside-down semi-colons. There are not many patterns. They boil down to only six, sketched below. (I've used 9 and 6 here for the normal and upside-sown semicolons and a dot for the colon. That makes the patterns clearer.)
>
> ```
>       4 times (. . . . 9 . . .)
>       5 times (. . . 9 . . . .)
>       6 times (. . 9 . . 9 . .)
>       6 times (. 9 . . . . 9 .)
>       4 times (9 . . . . . . 9)
>       4 times (6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6)
> ```

Now if we ...

> ... organize the capitals by these patterns and also look up their countries, we get:
>
> ```
>              Astana (. . . . 9 . . .) Kazakhstan
>           New Delhi (. . . . 9 . . .) India
>              Niamey (. . . . 9 . . .) Niger
>              Athens (. . . . 9 . . .) Greece
>
>                   ? (. . . 9 . . . .)
>          Montevideo (. . . 9 . . . .) Uruguay
>               Quito (. . . 9 . . . .) Ecuador
>        San Salvador (. . . 9 . . . .) El Salvador
>             Belfast (. . . 9 . . . .) Northern Ireland
>
>            Brussels (. . 9 . . 9 . .) Belgium
>              Dublin (. . 9 . . 9 . .) Ireland
>            Khartoum (. . 9 . . 9 . .) Sudan
>            Budapest (. . 9 . . 9 . .) Hungary
>                   ? (. . 9 . . 9 . .)
>              Warsaw (. . 9 . . 9 . .) Poland
>
>             Bishkek (. 9 . . . . 9 .) Kyrgyzstan
>            Windhoek (. 9 . . . . 9 .) Namibia
>             Jakarta (. 9 . . . . 9 .) Indonesia
>             Tbilisi (. 9 . . . . 9 .) Georgia
>         Tegucigalpa (. 9 . . . . 9 .) Honduras
>       Port of Spain (. 9 . . . . 9 .) Trinidad & Tobago
>
>           Bucharest (9 . . . . . . 9) Romania
>                   ? (9 . . . . . . 9)
>                   ? (9 . . . . . . 9)
>             Nairobi (9 . . . . . . 9) Kenia
>
>              Lisbon (6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6) Portugal
>        Buenos Aires (6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6) Argentina
>             Cardiff (6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6) Wales
>                Oslo (6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6) Norway
> ```

We see ...

> ... that the patterns are the starting positions or files of the six chess pieces. The pawns (6) are on the second row or rank; the other pieces (9) are on the first row. (That's also what the title suggests: Capitals turned into **pieces**.)
>
>  The countries' first letters spell the names of the pieces, **pawn**, **rook**, **knight**, **bishop**, **queen** and **king**. Clearly, we are missing a **Q** for queen and and **O** for rook and bishop.
>
>  There is only one country that starts with O, Oman, and only one country that starts with Q, Qatar. The capitals of these two countries, **Muscat** and **Doha**, must fill the spaces.

Comment: you see more than me, o great one! :)

Comment: This is the correct answer, well done!

Comment: Being nitpicky - The starting position for white, not black (K and Q)